# Apply the if else loop on the float data type in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, floating-point

I want to apply this function on the column that has the float values and i do not want to change the values to int data type as it would result in the loss of the information. I am getting the error *''float' object has no attribute 'Radiation''*
Whats the solution to this problem as i do want to keep the float data type and perform the if elese loop

[image: radiation column values]

=======

**function to find the Day**

```
def wplyer(row):
        if  row.Radiation == 0: 
            return 'Yes' ##### Night value
        else:
            return'No'
    tp= df2_all_rows['Radiation'].apply(wplyer)
    df2_all_rows['Day status'] = tp
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Change the indentation so the last 2 lines aren't in the function.

Comment: @datanovice..I want to use a column that has float values and apply if else statement on it to make another column having information .The new column would be day status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying the function row-wise to a column, so each input is a value of that column, which is a float.

However, your function expects that it is applied row-wise to a dataframe, such that row is a named tuple that you can access using row.Radiation. That is why you are getting the error - you are trying to access a property called "Radiation" on a float and, of course, the float has no such property.

In any event, you don't need to use `apply` to accomplish your ends.

```
df2_all_rows['Day status'] = 'No'
df2_all_rows.loc[df2_all_rows['Radiation'] == 0, 'Day status'] = 'Yes'
```

Comment: I want to apply it on the column Radiation so can you tell me how to take the column values also Day status would be a new column that would be added after the operation is applied